# Python docx extracting Font name and size

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I want to code a program in python which checks some properties of an MS Word file (.docx) like margins and font name and font size.
(before moving forward I should note that Honestly, I have no clue what am I doing)

for the font part I've faced real problems:
according to:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html

"A style can inherit properties from another style, somewhat similarly to how Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) works.
Inheritance is specified using the base_style attribute. By basing one style on another, an inheritance hierarchy of arbitrary depth can be formed.
A style having no base style inherits properties from the document defaults."

so I tried this code:

```
d = Document('1.docx')
d_styles = d.styles

for st in d_styles:
    if st.name != "No List": #Ignoring The Numbering Style
        print(st.type, st.name, st.base_style)
        #print(dir(st.base_style), '\n') there is no such thing as font in dir(st.base_style)
```

st.base_style returns "None"

so based on "A style having no base style inherits properties from the `document defaults`" the answer should lie down in this part. But I don't know how to reach it.

Codes below also returned "None":

```
for st in d_styles:
    if st.name != "No List": #Ignoring The Numbering Style
        print(st.font.name)
#Outputs: None
```

```
for para in d.paragraphs:
    for r in para.runs:
        print (r.font.name)
#Outputs: None
```

```
for para in d.paragraphs:
    print(para.style.font.name)
#Outputs: None
```

I've used these Sources:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html

---

edit:

I've tried to deal with style object as a dictionary:

```
for key, value in styles.items() :
    print (key, value)
#ERROR: 'Styles' object has no attribute 'items'
```

```
print(styles.items())
#ERROR: 'Styles' object has no attribute 'items'
```

```
print(styles.keys())
#ERROR: 'Styles' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

```
print(styles.values())
#ERROR: 'Styles' object has no attribute 'values'
```

even this piece of code returns None:

```
style = d.styles['Normal']
f = style.font
print(f.name)
```

Comment: I recommend having a look at the XML for the document and see what hints that gives you. Ultimately, `python-docx` is just a user-interface on the underlying XML documents. You can get a start with `print(d.styles["Normal"]._element.xml)`. If you don't find any font information there, that would explain getting `None` for font.name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help. No I could not find any font information, Unless I'm missing something: <w:style xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex"

Comment: xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" w:type="paragraph" w:default="1" w:styleId="Normal">
  <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
  <w:qFormat/>
</w:style>

Comment: Ok, so I expect this is falling back to the document default. I don't know exactly where that is defined, but I don't believe there is any API support for getting or setting it in `python-docx`.

Comment: Is there any update to this problem? I am also getting None for paragraph.style.font.name and size. however, I am able to retain text and the name of the style. Is this related to a bug in a library? I use the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

According to the document :

> The Styles object provides **dictionary-style** access to defined styles by name

And I think that is your problem. You are trying to access a dictionary as a list and that returns only the *keys* of the dictionary and not its values. Try the code-snippet below instead to see if it solves your problem or no. But for future references, try reading the [Style Document](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html) carefully.

For getting the key values of `style` use:

```py
d = Document('1.docx')
d_styles = d.styles
print(d_styles.keys())
```

After that, you can access each *value* of the dictionary using `d_styles['yourKey']`. For getting the values and keys together, try the snippet below.

```py
d = Document('1.docx')
d_styles = d.styles
for key in d_styles:
    print(f'{key} : {d_styles[key]}')
```

Keep in mind that each style (for example d_styles[key]) is also iterable meaning you can perform iteration on it. So the snippet below is also valid.

```py
d = Document('1.docx')
d_styles = d.styles
for key in d_styles:
    print(f'{key} : {d_styles[key]}')
    for val in d_styles[key]:
        print(val)
```

Play with keys and attributes a little bit and you'll find what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've already tried to deal with style object as a dictionary, I'll add the codes to the question, None of them works. For the last 2 snippets, this error is shown:   Exception has occurred: TypeError  
unhashable type: '_ParagraphStyle'

Comment: Try loading your file before hand and pass it to document constructor. I think you might be loading the default template instead.

Comment: Also try removing the first read line and add these two lines instead. `doc = Document ()` and after that `doc = doc.Document('1.docx')`.